# Java: Confusion with stacks

Tags: java, stack

Okay I have to create a program that determines `if a Stack of CalendarDates is sorted or not.` The parameter is using the stack:

```
CalendarDate[] store = {new CalendarDate(1,2), new CalendarDate(1,1), new CalendarDate(12,30)};
```

`So it will return false as (1,1) comes after (1,2).`

Anyways, here is my code:

```
public static boolean isSorted(Stack<CalendarDate> c){
    Queue<CalendarDate> q = new LinkedList<CalendarDate>();

    CalendarDate peek = c.peek();

    while (!c.empty()){
        CalendarDate peeker = c.peek();
        if (peeker.compareTo(peek)>0){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            q.add(c.pop());
            peek=peeker;
        }
    }
    while (!q.isEmpty()){
        c.push(q.remove());
    }
    while(!c.empty()){
        q.add(c.pop());
    }
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        c.push(q.remove());
    }
    return true;
}
```

> The only error I get is in the 3rd line where I say CalendarDate peek
>   = c.peek(); It is a "emptystackexception"

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Are you sure your stack isn't empty?

Comment: Because the stack was empty at that time... You probably passed an empty stack to the function.

Comment: The error is very self explanatory. Don't over-think it.

Comment: "Thrown by methods in the Stack class to indicate that the stack is empty." Seen [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EmptyStackException.html). I suggest you put a check in there and verify your beliefs.

Comment: FYI: Your method will corrupt the stack. The first `while` loop will begin to `pop()` values off the stack, then detect an out-of-order value and instantly return `false`, *without restoring the stack*. --- And what is the purpose of the last two `while` loops? Change `q` to `Deque` and use it as a stack, then those two extra loops will be unnecessary.

Comment: Are you just adding the data within your isSorted method?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Stack` is descendant of `List`, you can write your algirithm without using pop/push/peek, just iterate the stack (which is a list) using an iterator:

```
public static boolean isSorted(Stack<CalendarDate> c){

   Iterator<CalendarDate> it = c.iterator();
   CalendarDate lastItem = null;

   while( it.hasNext() ){

       CalendarDate currentItem = it.next();

       if( lastItem != null && lastItem.compareTo( currentItem ) > 0 ){
           return false;
       }

       lastItem = currentItem;
   }

   return true;
}
```